# Induction and restriction of unitary representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, unitary-representations

$\DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}\DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}$Given a locally compact group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H\subset G$,
let $\Rep(G)$ and $\Rep(H)$ denote their categories of (strongly continuous) unitary representations on Hilbert spaces.
Let $NG$ be the group von Neumann algebra of $G$ (the weak closure of the left action of $G$ on $L^2G$),
and let $NH$ be the group von Neumann algebra of $H$.

We have full subcategories $\Rep(NG)\subset \Rep(G)$, and $\Rep(NH)\subset \Rep(H)$. (The category $\Rep(NG)$ can also be described as the full subcategory of $\Rep(G)$ consisting of reps which are direct sums of direct summands of the regular representation.)

> It is well-known that the restriction and induction functors
> $\Res: \Rep(G) \to \Rep(H)$
> and
> $\Ind: \Rep(H) \to \Rep(G)$               defined by   $\Ind(V) = L^2(G/H , G\times_HV)$
> are ***NOT*** each other's adjoints in any sense (see for example [this previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83336/induced-representations-of-topological-groups)).

But maybe I'll be more lucky if I restrict these functors to the subcategories $\Rep(NG)$ and $\Rep(NH)$?

> $\Res: \Rep(NG) \to \Rep(NH)$
> and
> $\Ind: \Rep(NH) \to \Rep(NG)$

Is there any relationship between the two latter functors which can be formulated in category-theoretic terms?
More precisely, is there an $NH$-$NG$-bimodule $X$ such that $\Res: \Rep(NG) \to \Rep(NH)$ is given by tensoring by $X$, and $\Ind: \Rep(NH) \to \Rep(NG)$ is given by tensoring by the complex conjugate of $X$?

One result in that direction is this old theorem of Mackey (from [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969786?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can take $\overline X = {}_{N(G)}L^2(G)_{N(H)}$ using the canonical inclusion of $N(H)$ into $N(G)$ to restrict the "trivial" correspondence $L^2(G)$ to a $N(G)-N(H)$ correspondence.

(I am assuming here "bimodule" is a "correspondence" in the sense of Connes, i.e. a Hilbert space with commuting, normal actions of $N(G)$ and $N(H)^o$.  The (tensor) product is the Connes fusion, aka the Sauvageot relative tensor product ([Sur le produit tensoriel rélatif d’espaces de Hilbert](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0517.46050)).  See also Takesaki, Volume 2, Chapter IX, Section 3.)

Restriction is easy to check.  As $N(G)$ acts in standard form on $L^2(G)$, we know that ${}_{N(G)}L^2(G)_{N(G)}$ is self-dual, so $X \cong {}_{N(H)}L^2(G)_{N(G)}$.  From Takesaki, Prop 3.19, we know that if ${}_{N(G)}H$ is any left $N(G)$-module then ${}_{N(G)}L^2(G)_{N(G)} \otimes {}_{N(G)}H \cong {}_{N(G)}H$.  So ${}_{N(H)}X_{N(G)} \otimes {}_{N(G)}H \cong {}_{N(H)}H$, which *is* restriction.

---

Checking that we get induction seems harder.  I think if $G$ is discrete, or more generally $H$ open, this can be done with a long but elementary computation.  I want to give an indication of the general case, which involves analytic difficulties.

First a sanity check: if we induce the left-regular representation $\lambda_H$ we get $\lambda_G$.  So we wish to induce $L^2(H)$ to $L^2(G)$ as $N(H)$ and $N(G)$ modules.  But $\overline X_{N(H)} \otimes {}_{N(H)}L^2(H)$ can indeed be shown to be isomorphic to ${}_{N(G)} L^2(H)$ (see below).  As any left module of $N(H)$ is obtained by direct sum and subrepresentation of $L^2(H)$, and as induction respects direct sums, this would seem to indicate that we get what we want.  However, I see no "soft" way of checking that all the isomorphisms involved really do commute.  That is, if $\pi_1 \oplus \pi_2 \cong \lambda_H$ then both "induction" methods give modules of $N(G)$ which sum to $\lambda_G$, but I do not see why the individual components are automatically isomorphic.

Perhaps there is some way to use imprimivity, but I also do not see this.

---

Instead, I want to build "models" of induction, and tensoring by $\overline X$, which are manifestly the same.  I will use the model of induction which works by using a (suitably measurable) cross section $G/H \rightarrow G$.  This is "Realization III" in Kaniuth and Taylor's book (page 79-80).  We can deal with any locally compact $G$ by using results of [Kehlet - Cross sections for quotient maps of locally compact groups](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0565.22004).  Following Kehlet and page 3494 of [Daws et al. - Closed quantum subgroups of locally compact quantum groups](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1275.46057) (I thank in particular my coauthor Pawel here) we pick a quasi-invariant measure $\lambda$ on $G/H$ and then we find a unitary
$$ T: L^2(G/H,\lambda) \otimes L^2(H) \rightarrow L^2(G), $$
with $T(1\otimes \rho^H(h))T^* = \rho^G(h)$ for $h\in H$, where $\rho^H$ and $\rho^G$ are the right-regular reps of $H$ and $G$, respectively.

If you perform the calculation, you'll also find that
$$ T U^{\lambda_H}(g) T^* = \lambda^G(g) \qquad (g\in G), $$
where $\lambda^G$ is the left-regular representation of $G$, and $U^{\lambda_H}$ is the induced representation of the left-regular representation of $H$, up to $G$.  Thus we have our "model" of induction.  Clearly, if $\pi$ is a sub-representation of $\lambda^H$ then we get the "same" model by restricting $T$ to $L^2(G/H,\lambda) \otimes K$ where $K\subseteq L^2(H)$ is the $N(H)$-invariant subspace associated to $\pi$.  (Really "clearly" here means follow the isomorphisms through.)

What about tensoring with $\overline X$?  I don't want to compute with the Sauvageot tensor product, as that would involve consideration of vectors in $L^2(G)$ bounded with respect to the Plancheral measure on $N(H)$ etc.  Instead, I'll use a realisation of correspondences as self-dual Hilbert $C^*$-bimodules (see work of Reiffel and Paschke).  For von Neumann algebras $M$, $N$ this identifies ${}_M H_N$ with
$$ \hom_N(L^2(N), {}_MH_N) $$
the bounded linear maps $t:L^2(N)\rightarrow H$ with $t(\xi n) = t(\xi)n$ for $n\in N$.  Composition of operators defines a left $M$ and right $N$ module structure, and we get an $N$-valued inner-product by setting $(t|s) = t^*s$.  Note that $t^*s$ is an operator on $L^2(N)$ which commutes with the right $N$-action on $L^2(N)$, that is, can be identified with an element of $N$.

Conversely, given a bimodule ${}_MY_N$ we take the balanced tensor product $Y_N \otimes_N L^2(N)$ which gives a Hilbert space, and this space inherits the left $M$ action from ${}_M X$ and the right $N$ action from $L^2(N)$, so becoming a correspondence.

Our $\overline X = {}_{N(G)} L^2(G)_{N(H)}$ is identified with
$$ \hom_{N(H)}(L^2(H), L^2(G)) $$
and if $K\subseteq L^2(H)$ is a sub-rep of $\lambda_H$, then $\overline X \otimes K$ is identified with the left $N(G)$-module
$$ \hom_{N(H)}(L^2(H), L^2(G)) \otimes_{N(H)} K. $$
This, by definition, is the separation-completion of the algebraic tensor product for the scalar-valued inner-product
$$ (t_1\otimes\xi_1 | t_2\otimes\xi_2) = (\xi_1 | t_1^*t_2 \xi_2)_{K}, $$
where $t_1^*t_2 \in N(H)$ and so acts on $K$.  However, this is simply
$$ (t_1(\xi_1)| t_2(\xi_2))_{L^2(G)}, $$
which makes sense as $K\subseteq L^2(H)$.  Thus $\overline X \otimes K$ is identified with a subspace of $L^2(G)$; the left $N(G)$-action works as expected.  The space we get is the closed linear span of $\{t(K) : t\in \hom_{N(H)}(L^2(H), L^2(G)) \}$.

We want to understand $\hom_{N(H)}(L^2(H), L^2(G))$.  Apply the unitary $T$ to identify $L^2(G)$ with $L^2(G/H)\otimes L^2(H)$.  Due to the above commutation of the right-regular representations, the right $N(H)$ action is intertwined by $T$.  So we get
$$ \hom_{N(H)}(L^2(H), L^2(G/H)\otimes L^2(H)) = \{ t:L^2(H) \to L^2(G/H)\otimes L^2(H) : tn' = (1\otimes n')t \ (n'\in N(H)')\}. $$
As $K$ is the range of a projection $e\in N(H)'$ we see that $t(K) = te(L^2(H)) = (1\otimes e)t(L^2(H))$ and as $t$ varies we obtain all of the image of $1\otimes e$, that is, $L^2(G/H) \otimes K$.

Conclude: both operations of "induction" respect sub-representations of $\lambda_H$ in the same way.  By taking direct sums, this shows that both versions of induction agree on all $N(H)$-modules, as required.