# When are induction and coinduction of representations of Lie groups isomorphic? When they are compact? Semisimple?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, adjoint-functors, induced-representations

This is in a sense a follow up on the popular question [Induction and Coinduction of Representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1534/induction-and-coinduction-of-representations), where this particular question is one of several points, and it is neglected.

It seems that the restriction functor of representations of Lie groups $H \hookrightarrow G$ has a left adjoint, induction, and a right adjoint, coinduction.
When are these functors isomorphic?

My guess was compact Lie groups, but I couldn't find anything on that. (It's true in 0 dimensions. Haha.)
Then in Kirillov's book "Elements of the theory of representations", I find the statement that they are isomorphic for semisimple *algebras*, which made me think of the possibility that it might be true for semisimple Lie groups/algebras.

Comment: Small edit: your "coadjoint" in line 4 is meant to be "coinduction".

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I add a link here to a related question of mine, also from 2014: https://mathoverflow.net/q/188571/41139. I think many of the references in the comments, answer and question itself have relevance for the question stated here. But besides that, the answer below stating that induction and coinduction are equal if $H$ is co-compact in $G$ seems to be at odds with the situation in that question where the two types of induction are not equal but the group $H$ (the minimal parabolic subgroup) is co-compact by the Iwasawa decomposition.

Comment: I will try and understand this seeming discrepancy better, but later. So a link is useful in finding the two questions again. (For instance I didn't see the current question when typing the linked question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion $H \to G$ induces a map of classifying stacks  $f \colon BH \to BG$ (note that these are *stacks*, not the "topologists $BG$"). As remarked in the question you linked to, induction and coinduction correspond to the functors $f_\ast$ and $f_!$ respectively. These functors will be equal if $f$ is proper. The fiber of $f$ is the quotient $G/H$, so a sufficient condition is that $H$ is cocompact in $G$.

Comment: Awesome, so compact homogeneous spaces are an example!

Comment: @Dan Petersen: Don't you also need the relative canonical class to be trivial?

Comment: @Sasha You may very well be right, but I don't understand why my argument doesn't cut it. Why do you need the condition on the relative canonical class?

Comment: @Dan Petersen: I think the question is in which category are you working --- if this is the category of constructible sheaves, then properness is probably enough, but if it is the category of coherent sheaves then I think you need the canonical class to be trivial.

Comment: @Sasha, if we're doing representation theory of Lie groups, were does a choice of sheaf category ever enter? In the choice of what kind of stack to consider?

Comment: @Turion: The question is whether you identify representations of $G$ with constructible sheaves on $BG$, or with coherent sheaves on $BG$.

Comment: @Sasha, I meant representations are representations and you can define them without ever referring to constructible sheaves or coherent sheaves, so the answer to the question should be independent of that, right?

Comment: @Turion: Of course. What I mean is that Dan in his answer implicitely identifies the category of representations with the category of sheaves on $BG$. But since he does not mention which sheaves are those, it is not clear which condition you really need.

Comment: @Sasha, I see, thanks. Dan, which sheaves do you mean then? I couldn't find any material that spells out this correspondence, but since I know close to nothing about stacks and sheaves, that's no surprise. Maybe you know an easier introduction or review where I could find that out?