# Understanding the purely formal part of the sheaf theoretic (cohomological) framework for representation theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

By now I have the impression that many statements in representation theory can be phrased a lot more elegantly using cohomological language. Therefore I'm trying to understand a bit better the sheaf theoretic framework for representation theory. To be specific I'd like to understand, for example, the purely formal parts (no hard "real" theorems) of the following ideas:

- Induction and Coinduction as different pushforwards of sheaves
- Equivariant sheaves as sheaves on quotient stacks and relation to the (Co-)induction functors.

I have some background in algebraic geometry and homological algebra (i'm even fine with some moderate stacky language) so I think I have the nessasary tools to understand this yet unfortunately I'm having a hard time finding references for statements appearing, for example, in the answers to the [following question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1534/induction-and-coinduction-of-representations).

Is there a source that tells the overall cohomological story of representation theory with some sketches of proofs for the obviously formal propositions? (for example that thing with induction and pushforward which looks entirely formal to me).

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be an affine group scheme (e.g. a finite group). There is a stack $BG$ which is more or less determined by either of the following two properties:

1. Maps to $BG$ are the same thing as $G$-torsors. More formally, there's a functor from commutative rings to groupoids sending a commutative ring $R$ to the groupoid of isomorphism classes of $G$-torsors over $\text{Spec } R$; this functor is represented by a stack called $BG$.
2. Quasicoherent sheaves on $BG$ are the same thing as representations of $G$.

If $f : H \to G$ is a map of affine group schemes, it induces a map $Bf : BH \to BG$ of stacks, which further induces a pullback functor $Bf^{\ast} : QC(BG)) \to QC(BH)$; as you might imagine, this is restriction of representations. Pullback has, as usual, a right adjoint, namely pushforward $Bf_{\ast} : QC(BH) \to QC(BG)$; this is one version of induction of representations (I guess it might be "coinduction," but I'm happy to just call it "induction" because this adjoint will, I think, always exist, so it ought to have the more fundamental name).

To get a better sense of what pushforward is doing, you can think of $BG$ as being the quotient stack $\text{pt}/G$, and $BH$ as being the quotient stack $(G/H)/G$; then you can think of representations of $G$ as $G$-equivariant sheaves on a point, and representations of $H$ as $G$-equivariant sheaves on $G/H$. This lets you interpret push/pull along the map $BH \to BG$ as $G$-equivariant push/pull along $G/H \to \text{pt}$.

In the nicest examples, where $G$ is reductive and $H$ is the Borel subgroup, $G/H$ will be a smooth projective variety (the flag variety of $G$); the significance of this is that $G$-equivariant pushforward from $G/H$ to a point (that is, taking global sections) now sends finite-dimensional representations of $H$ to finite-dimensional representations of $G$. What representations you get is described by the [Borel-Weil-Bott theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem), and for the nicest statements you should take the derived pushforward.

It's unclear to me what part of this story is "purely formal." You can write down adjoints all day, but this feature that sometimes induction sends finite-dimensional things to finite-dimensional things even though $H$ isn't finite index in $G$ doesn't seem formal to me. Also, I don't know a reference for any of this.

Comment: This is great stuff thanks! So the equivalence of stacks between $(G/H)/G$ and $pt/H$ is purely formal?

Comment: @Saal: yes. It makes more sense if I write the quotient by $G$ on the left but I've forgotten how to do that in LaTeX.

Comment: So is there a phrasing of Borel-Weil-Bott which says something like "the derived pushforward on coherent sheaves from $Coh((G/H)/G)$ to $Coh(pt/G)$ decsends to an equivalence of grothendiek groups or something similar in vane? (maybe weaker or stronger).

Comment: Yes Borel Weil Bott can be rewritten as the description of sheaves on BG as modules for a monad on BH, and the identification of that monad as a graded version of the Weyl group

Comment: Here H= the torus, which you shouldn't consider as a subgroup of G but via the correspondence G <-- B --> H for B a Borel

Comment: Here and elsewhere W appears in the form of B\G/B, the self fiber product of BB over BG. BTW this formulation of BWB I learned from Sam Gunningham's thesis

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi (Medium to High enthusiasm:) Is the monad in your statement the one you get from the composition of the push/pull (with some possible shrieks) adjunctions $BG \leftarrow BB \rightarrow BH$? (Very High enthsiasm) : "identification of that monad as a graded version of the Weyl group" Where can I find more about this?! I tried googling "Sam Gunningham" along with other stuff and nothing turned up. Finally I must confess I'm a die hard fan of yours, I can't thank you enough for all your insightful comments and answers on this site!